# Changing the html file for apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, cmd

I recently bought a domain and put a html and css file to apache by using ubuntu(I dont even remember the exact commands.)Anyway now I want to change them.I removed the css file with cd /var/www/html and writing sudo rm blabla.css .But I am not sure about writing rm index.html since I am not sure what will be the effects.Also for some reason I got some problems when I tried to move my other css and html files.How can I accomplish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the commands mentioned here you can see their help pages ie their manuals on Ubuntu by using

```
man rm
man cp
man rsync
```

etc. This command

```
rm index.html
```

Will remove the file completely ie if you hit your domain

```
http://www.example.com/
```

you will likely get an error indicating no page or depending on how your server is setup it might list the directory contents. Normally when editing a personal website people copy the new files over the top of the old one ie using something like rsync/ftp etc.

For instance if you do this

```
cp foo.html index.html
```

the `cp` command will overwrite the index.html file with the contents of foo.html. If you use ftp it will do the same thing but this time if you edit `index.html` on machine A and ftp it to machine b it effectively does this

```
cp machineA/index.html machineB/index.html
```

This allows you to work on one machine and copy the changes to the other.

Comment: I have filezilla I think that should work since you mentioned about ftp.But what do you mean by over?

Comment: You should start reading the manuals for the commands your using.

Comment: I am convinced by your answer but one small question was created in the process.When I try to move my css file to my website with filezilla it works if my target is a random folder.but it does not work when my target is /var/www.I think I have no permission to change what is in there.Is it correct

Comment: You're correct, it's almost certainly a permissions issue. You can see who owns things using `ls -la`, in the case of /var/www on Ubuntu it's likely `root`.

Comment: What I did to accomplish my goal was the following.First I put my files to a place where I had permission with Filezilla.Then I moved them to /var/www/html with putty using sudo mv.Is this a good approach?